# Is it possible to specify a cache validator for a PHP file that serves JS content?

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess, caching

I've tried various methods and so far have the following in .htaccess:

```
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"

# 1 month exp
ExpiresActive On
<filesMatch ".(gpdf|PDF|gif|ico|jpg|jpeg|png|GIF|ICO|JPG|JPEG|PNG|css|js|woff|CSS|JS|WOFF|ttf|TTF|txt|TXT|html|HTML)$">
  Header unset Set-Cookie
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000"
  Header unset ETag
  FileETag None
</filesMatch>
```

And the PHP file that serves the JS content has the following headers:

```
header('Content-type: application/javascript');
header("Cache-control: max-age=2592000, must-revalidate");
```

When I go to do a speed-test it still shows "specify a cache validator for js.php"

Is what I'm doing even possible or am I just missing something?

**EDIT:**
Response headers for the file in question:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 24 Jun 2017 23:14:33 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.23 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.26
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Cache-Control: max-age=2592000, must-revalidate, max-age=2592000
Expires: Mon, 24 Jul 2017 23:14:33 GMT
Connection: keep-alive, Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 7436
Keep-Alive: timeout=30, max=100
Content-Type: application/javascript
```

Comment: This "error" implies you are missing the `Last-Modified` and/or `ETag` HTTP response headers? Please include the complete HTTP response headers for this resource.

Comment: @user82217, I've added the response headers above. How would I go about adding the last-modified header?

Comment: @user82217, Thanks for your help, I've managed to figure out an answer below :)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @user82217, I've managed to figure out and put together an answer.

The line I was missing was the last-modified header in the php file itself.

I had:

```
header('Content-type: application/javascript');
header("Cache-control: max-age=2592000, must-revalidate");
```

And needed to append:

```
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s T', filemtime(__FILE__)));
```

This gives the file the last-modified header in the correct format in GMT for the script file it's being executed in.

This fixed my issue!